# How to install NumPy on PyCharm?

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, installation-package

I have already installed *NumPy* on *cmd* and is running on idle but in PyCharm, it says:

> ```sh
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads`
>
> proposed solution
>
> **Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\ACER\This PC\Downloads\Video\pycharm\venv\Scripts\python.exe'.**
> ```

Comment: Have you tried to install Microsoft Visual C++ mentioned in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

Is your virtual environment made with a version of Python that numpy has binary wheels for? [As of this post](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files), that means Python 3.5-3.8, 32-bit or 64-bit Intel.

If yes (you can check by running the Python REPL, i.e. `venv\Scripts\python`), you can try upgrading the packaging toolchain and install again. Run the following commands in the command line (from the `pycharm` directory named in the error):

```
venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -U numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this command in terminal and it works
venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -U